# Sand Physics for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, game-physics, collision

What is the best way to make sand particles animate in a view?
Essentially, I would like to half fill the iOS device's screen with small sand-like particles, then allow a user to rotate and shake the device to dictate the sand's position.

Assuming I have never done any physics programming before, can anyone recommend a tutorial or show me how it's done?

Thank you,

Query.

**UPDATE:**
I have now come across [this](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/granular/) (mine should be 2D though) - how can I bring something similar into my app?

Comment: Be aware that dry sand has an "angle of repose" that is essentially the slope of the side of the cone-shaped pile you'd make if you drizzle the sand out of a small chute above the pile.  Rounder sand particles have a shallower angle of repose, sharp/angular particles have a steeper angle of repose.

Comment: (You might get some further ideas from the [Physics Stack Exchange forum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: thank you - I will have a look at physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Using [spatial indexing](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves) for finding the nearest-particles to check for collision and using an [integration technique](http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/aug/28/integration-by-example-euler-vs-verlet-vs-runge-kutta/) for the transition between force(acceleration)-velocity-position and using only gravity force as an outer-fource would give you your sand-box.

You will need to select a good [exclusion-force derived from a particle-potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) if you use post-collision detection.

I advise you to use the Truncated Lennar-Jones potential and Verlet-Integrator. Easier than Runge-Kutta's and more precise than Euler's. Because it is used in molecular-dynamics. You dont need to use other forces . Just use exclusion force, gravity and wall forces.

If you have bullets in your simulator, you can use Euler-Integration for them. I think this is acceptable for free-falling but not colliding sand particles. After they close each-other, it would be good to use Verlet or Runge-Kutta.

All i mentioned above assumes your integration step is so big that energy is not conserved and even decreased. If your integration is good enough to conserve energy, you will need to give your particles [friction force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction) to make sands slow or you will get your particles exploding everwhere.

Comment: Thank you - I will use this information when I get to the coding part. Still not sure where to start though.... Box2d?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd try to model each sand particle -- computationally intensive.  Rather, you could probably treat it as a sort of fluid flow problem, though with a non-Newtonian fluid.  (The opposite of the [corn starch trick](http://www.exploratorium.edu/science_explorer/ooze.html) -- sand becomes hard when not moving, and fluid when moving.)

Comment: Ah! That's very clever! Solid sand: will do! Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

If you like to make it on iphone then you have to think of certain optimizations and tricks as iPhone can't really simulate water or sand.

Your trick is that most of your work is to draw scene.

Create scene in Box2D with balls at size 10-20 times bigger then sand particle.

iPhone would be able to simulate it.

Then you should draw 10-20 sand particle per ball.

Every frame you may check if ball collides with other balls or not.

If balls is not colliding then these sand particles are in the air and you should draw them on certain distance one from each other.

If ball collides with other balls then particles should be rendered together

You may also detect margin and render glider sand border on top.